# Passing a book-keeping parameter to Qiskit Ibm Runtime Estimator

Tags: qiskit, qiskit-runtime

I have a `Qiskit.QuantumCircuit` object `circ` which prepares the state $| \Psi \rangle$, and a `qiskit.quantum_info.SparsePauliOp` object `H`. I wish to evaluate the expectation value $\langle \Psi | \hat{H} | \Psi \rangle$ via

```
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService

service = QiskitRuntimeService()
backend = service.backend("ibmq_qasm_simulator")    

with Session(backend=backend):
    estimator = Estimator()
```

I would like to pass some book-keeping parameter $l$ to the `Estimator` such that I can search for a particular job from `QiskitRuntimeService` which ran with a particular value $l=l^\prime$. For instance, I wish to do something like

```
with Session(backend=backend):
    estimator = Estimator(l=1)
```

so that once the estimator jobs are finished I can retrieve only the jobs with $l=1$ by performing something like

```
service = QiskitRuntimeService()
results_with_l_1 = service.jobs(backend_name=backend, l=1)
```

Is there a way to do this. Encoding this information either to the `json` file created by the service, or into the `estimator.result()` object will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve this is to use `job_tags`. Just pass tags to `Estimator.run()` method

```
job = estimator.run(circuit, observable, job_tags=['tag1', 'tag2'])
```

Later on, you can use them to filter the jobs

```
service.jobs(job_tags=['tag1'])
```